# Do any sects prohibit all images?

Tags: image

Are there any groups that prohibit all images including Internet graphics/images for art & entertainment, etc.?

Comment: can you elaborate on what is your definition of sects?, and in the text of your question i find you referring to groups. are they one and the same thing?, or are you referring to the narration about 73 sects that muslims will divide and the 4 major groups/schools of thought?. without comprehending the question fully, it would not be wise to provide an answer just based on assumptions. if you can include more details, it would be better.